# "Stack around the variable was corrupted" error

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to read a char value using fgets as follows:

```
int main() {
    char m_cityCharCount;

    // Input the number of cities
    fgets(&m_cityCharCount, 4, stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio returns this error after the code is executed - `Stack around the variable m_cityCharCount was corrupted`

Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: size of `char` is 1 in C, not 4. example of modifications: `char m_cityCharCount[16];fgets(m_cityCharCount, sizeof m_cityCharCount, stdin);`

Comment: `fgets` is intended to read zero-terminated *strings*. You are using a single `char` as a recipient buffer, which is only enough for an empty zero-terminated string. And while doing that you are lying to `fgets` with that `4`. Your recipient buffer consist of only `1` `char`, not `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter of fgets() is pointer on buffer (size of it should be great or equals than second parameter. But sizeof(char) == 1)

```
int main() {
    char m_cityCharCount[4];

   // Input the number of cities
   fgets(m_cityCharCount, 4, stdin);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`m_cityCharCount` is a char, it can hold one char at the most, but you are telling `fgets` it is 4 bytes buffer. Even if you input nothing but hit the enter key, `fgets` will store the new line AND the null terminator to the buffer, which of cause is a serious problem. You need a bigger buffer to do `fgets`:

```
char str[4096];
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
```